# How can I show a list of objects that have "Review" as the parent object in Visualforce email template?

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template

I am trying to create an email where it will show the recipient a list of the "Review Accounts" associated with the "Review" object. Where "Review Accounts" is a Child object for "Reviews". Below is what I have but it keeps giving me the "Error: Invalid field LLC_BI__Review_Account__r for Object LLC_BI__Review__c"

```
<messageing:emailTemplate subject="testing email" recipientType="User" 
                          relatedToType="LLC__BI_Review__c">
  <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    <apex:repeat var="ra" value="{!relatedTo.LLC_BI__Review_Account__r}">

    </apex:repeat>
  </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a managed package here, it looks like your definition of the relationship name has the incorrect name space `LLC_BI`

You have:

```
value="{!relatedTo.LLC_BI__Review_Account__r}"
```

But the namespace looks like it is `LLC` based on the `relatedToType`

So you want:

```
value="{!relatedTo.LLC__BI_Review_Account__r}"
```

assuming that is the true relationship name; more likely, it is plural

```
value="{!relatedTo.LLC__BI_Review_Accounts__r}"
```

Check your configuration to get the correct relationship name

Comment: You were correct, it needed to be plural. I must have mistyped the namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the help!